# Regex - optional capture group after wildcard

Tags: regex

Say I have the following list:

> ```
> No 1 And Your Bird Can Sing (4)
> No 2 Baby, You're a Rich Man (5)
> No 3 Blue Jay Way S
> No 4 Everybody's Got Something to Hide Except Me and My Monkey (1)
> ```

And I want to extract the number, the title and the number of weeks in the parenthesis if it exists.

Works, but the last group is not optional ([regstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=No%20%28%3F%3Cno%3E%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%29%20%28%3F%3Ctitle%3E.*%3F%29%20%5C%28%28%3F%3Cweeks%3E%5Cd%29%5C%29&i=No%201%20And%20Your%20Bird%20Can%20Sing%20%284%29%0D%0ANo%202%20Baby%2C%20You%27re%20a%20Rich%20Man%20%285%29%0D%0ANo%203%20Blue%20Jay%20Way%20S%0D%0ANo%204%20Everybody%27s%20Got%20Something%20to%20Hide%20Except%20Me%20and%20My%20Monkey%20%281%29%0D%0A%0D%0A&o=m)):

`No (?<no>\d{1,3}) (?<title>.*?) \((?<weeks>\d)\)`

Last group optional, only matches number ([regstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=No%20%28%3F%3Cno%3E%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%29%20%28%3F%3Ctitle%3E.*%3F%29%28%20%5C%28%28%3F%3Cweeks%3E%5Cd%29%5C%29%29%3F&i=No%201%20And%20Your%20Bird%20Can%20Sing%20%284%29%0D%0ANo%202%20Baby%2C%20You%27re%20a%20Rich%20Man%20%285%29%0D%0ANo%203%20Blue%20Jay%20Way%20S%0D%0ANo%204%20Everybody%27s%20Got%20Something%20to%20Hide%20Except%20Me%20and%20My%20Monkey%20%281%0D%0A%0D%0A&o=m)):

`No (?<no>\d{1,3}) (?<title>.*?)( \((?<weeks>\d)\))?`

Combining one pattern with week capture with a pattern without week capture works, but there gotta be a better way:

```
(No (?<no>\d{1,3}) (?<title>.*) \((?<weeks>\d)\))|(No (?<no>\d{1,3}) (?<title>.*))
```

I use C# and javascript but I guess this is a general regex question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is almost there!

First and most importantly, you should add a `$` at the end. This makes `(?<title>.*?)` match all the way towards the end of the string. Currently, `(?<title>.*?)` matches an empty string and then stops, because it realises that it has reached a point where the rest of the regex matches. Why does the rest of the regex match? Because the optional group can match any empty string. By putting the `$`, you are making the rest of the regex "harder" to match.

Secondly, you forgot to match an open parenthesis `\(`.

This is how your regex should look like:

```
No (?<no>\d{1,3}) (?<title>.*?)( \((?<weeks>\d)\))?$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/d9GzC8/1)

Comment: Thank you, this works brilliantly and is short and sweet!

Comment: (I fixed missing \( in second regex in my question)

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex with an optional last part:

```
^No (?<no>\d{1,3}) (?<title>.*?\S)(?: \((?<weeks>\d)\))?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4xvKdu/1)

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be for the title to match either not `(` or when it does encounter a `(` it should not be followed by a digit and a closing parenthesis.

```
^No (?<no>\d{1,3}) (?<title>(?:[^(\r\n]+|\((?!\d\)))+)(?:\((?<weeks>\d)\))?
```

In parts

- `^No`
- `(?\d{1,3})`  Group `no` and space
- `(?<title>`

  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `[^(\r\n]+` Match any char except `(` or newline
    - `|` Or
    - `\((?!\d\))` Match `(` if not directly followed by a digit and `)`
  - `)+` Close group and repeat 1+ times
- `)` Close group title
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\((?<weeks>\d)\)` Group `weeks` between parenthesis
- `)?` Close group and make it optional

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b2VbMt/1)

If you don't want to trim the last space of the title you could exclude it from matching before the weeks.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zJE954/1)